# Detecting If Object and Object From ArrayList Collide

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I am in the process of writing a program for a java mini-game. I need to determine if two objects collide. One of the object is just of type Player (one single object) with the name of `player` and the other is part of an arrayList of object type Enemy with the name of the arrayList being `enemies`. I know that I can use the `intersect()` function because they both extend Rectangle. However, I am wondering what exactly the syntax of this statement would be? i.e. - `player.intersect(enemies)`. However, this does not seem to be correct?

Comment: How is the `ArrayList` relevant?  Why do you care where the `Enemy` came from?  You (presumably) only care if it intersects with the `Player`.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you're trying to do and what isn't working (an [mcve]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `enemies` is a list, you can't directly call `intersect` on the list. What you can do instead is loop through the list:

```
static boolean anyEnemyCollides(Player player, List<Enemy> enemies) {
    for  (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
        if  (player.intersect(enemy)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edit**:

I should also mention that if you're using guava, you can do:

```
Iterables.any(enemies, (enemy) -> player.intersect(enemy));
```